# Loop until player input matches + strange bug(?)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This question was originally going to be about how to write a while loop that asks for input until the user gives the correct word (I couldn't figure it out), but in my quest on figuring it out (from posts that this may be a duplicate of), I found something that baffles me.

```
while True:

    user_input = input("Enter 'test': ")

    # the line ("test") works fine but if I add the all-caps
    # version it no longer accepts ANYTHING and just keeps
    # printing "Invalid input!"
    if user_input == ("test", "TEST"):
        print("Correct input!")
        break
    else:
        print ("Invalid input!")
```

The output looks something like:

```
"Enter 'test': "

>>> test

"Invalid input!"
```

EDIT: Also note that I am a complete beginner! I just finished learning everything yesterday (although not a lot of it stuck, which is why I'm here!).

Comment: `if user_input in ("test", "TEST"):` .. you are not entering tuples - input create strings - why do you compare against a tuple? You could as well:  `user_input = input("Enter 'test': ").lower()` - sou you only need to compare against lower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:

user_input = input("Enter 'test': ")

# the line ("test") works fine but if I add the all-caps
# version it no longer accepts anything and just keeps
# printing "Invalid input!"
if user_input == ("test" or "TEST"):
    print("Correct input!")
    break
else:
    print ("Invalid input!")
```

Instead of ',' use or operator when giving users options to choose

Answer (score 0):

you are matching string with a tuple. that's why it is continuously printing invalid input. you can try the following code in the if statement for case insensitive matching:

```
if user_input.lower() == "test":
```